# Difference between conditions of symmetricity about origin and symmetricity in all 4 quadrants

Tags: calculus, curves

I am a high school student studying calculus through YouTube lectures. The lecturer said that if replacing $(x,y)$ with $(-x,-y)$ makes no change, the curve is symmetric about origin. But if we replace $x$ with $-x$ and $y$ with $-y$ and we get no change then the curve is symmetric in all the 4 quadrants. I don't get what is the difference between both the conditions.
Probably the condition for symmetricity in 4 quadrants means that if we have the curve as $f(x,y) = 0$ then $f(-x,y) = 0$ and $f(x,-y) = 0$ represent the same curve. Although I think that it will have symmetricity in 1st , 2nd and 4th quadrant only not in 3rd quadrant.

But for the condition of symmetricity about origin, I can't understand what does this mean at all.

(The above analysis is for any curve not just functions)

Comment: Symmetry about origin would mean that whatever you have in the 1st quadrant will be the same in 3rd quadrant (similarily for 2nd and 4th quadrant). Note that a function maybe only defined in the 1st and 3rd quadrant (or 2nd and 4th). As an example, consider $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\sqrt{x^2+y^2} & \text{if } x \geq 0, y\geq 0\\ \sqrt{x^2+y^2} & \text{if } x \leq 0, y\leq 0\end{cases}.$$

Comment: @AnuragA thanks for replying. My doubt was about the conditions to check symmetricity. (Sorry, I forgot to clarify but the analysis was for any curves not only in functions)

Comment: The geometrical interpretation I have mentioned will still hold true for any curve.

Comment: Symmetry about origin would be when we replace **both** $x$ and $y$ with $-x$ and $-y$ respectively and there is no change, whereas for symmetry in the 4 quadrants there should be no change when we replace even **one**, say $x$ with $-x$ but keeping $y$ constant.